# bounds test for cointegration (Pesaran ardl)

Tags: time-series

I am new to cointegration, particularly in the context of ARDL. Central to that approach is the bounds test where the null is (I believe) no cointegration. What confuses me is to run the test you have to know which of five cases your model consists of. One of the keys to this is if you have a restricted or unrestricted intercept (or no intercept). The second is whether you have a trend (restricted or not restricted). How do know whether you data (or model) has these or not? I have worked with ARDL and not encountered these terms before. Does a trend here mean if the data is stationary or not, these types of models can mix I(1) and I(0).

Comment: Have a look at this, may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9E8BKsocis&list=PLE1C9904FCBAC8FEA&index=5&t=0s

Comment: It helped some in that he makes it clear that you look for whether a trend makes sense or not. But I am not sure what theory would be used to use a constant or not and particularly if these are restricted or unrestricted (concepts I have not encountered before). I am also not sure if the models he is referencing is the original ARDL or the error correction model.

Answer (score 2):

The ARDL R package handles automatically any model (and turns it into an uecm if it is not already) and performs the test on the uecm.
About the selection of cases, I will probably write a blog post about it and I will add a throughout example in the upcoming vignette (I am the developer of the package).
Thank you for pointing into this direction, I will try to create an intuitive way for the selection.

Comment: You created an awesome package I would like to say. One thing that I hope you will address in your example is what code produces the long and short term estimates they speak of in bound testing. I saw several that I thought might generate the long term results - but I was not sure which did. From your comments I don't think it generates short term results yet (although you may have updated this already). If I understand comments I read about this package you got it while earning your doctorate, if so congratulations. Those are always painful.:)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind words and for giving it a try to use the package! I really appreciate it! The long term estimates (or long-run multipliers) can be extracted from both the ARDL and the Unrestricted ECM (The mathematical derivation of the long-run multipliers from each equation form is described in the description of the multipliers() function in the package manual https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ARDL/ARDL.pdf). These can be computed by multipliers(model) where model can be an ARDL or an UECM model. The next package version will include the short-run multipliers too.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a theory for including/excluding trends and constants in coitegration analysis. You may want to draw your dependent variable on a graph and see if it trends and if any other variables trend. If they do, include trend, and see if your variables drift, then include a constant so on and so forth. Also, if the trend/constant is not significant, you may not need it. Check if including these improve your model fit. etc. It is data-driven rather than theory.
The video I posted above should be of help.

Comment: thanks. All the references I have come across say you have to choose one of the 5 cases, as does the software, but not how you choose them. I have never heard of restricted versus unrestricted trends or constants outside this literature, including in the ARDL or ECM literature itself. I am also not clear if you have to use the ARDL model or a UECM form to test the cointegration. Do you know if the ARDL R package handles this automatically or you have to transform the data?